# Highlight table cell based on vertical and horizontal headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "football squares" game going, and I would like to highlight cells of the winners based on the top and side headers.

Now, I know they're not really headers but they serve the same purpose.

My table is located at this jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ybtntqg/

What I want to do is this:

Let's say the winner would be whoever is in the cell that lines up with TeamA - 2 and TeamZ - 9. That would be Mitch. I want to highlight Mitch's cell. How would I do this with Javascript or Jquery? I know how to do it if I was just looking for the word "Mitch", but I want to automatically do it, based on the numbers of TeamA and TeamZ.

I have this so far, but of course that only highlights the name but it's the only place I knew to start:

```
$('#table_id td').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'Mitch') {
    $(this).closest('td').css('background-color', '#f00');
 }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a data structure that holds the scores?  That would be better than searching the entire HTML table structure and doing string manipulation to find the values.

Comment: I could easily make one, which is what I was planning to do, but this is the part I can't figure out. I was just going to have a db with the scores. It would be the 1st qtr score, 2nd qtr score, 3rd qtr score, and 4th qtr score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of the column and row using jQuery's [**filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

That will give you direct access to the cell like so:

```
$('tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col).css('background-color', '#f00');
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function highlight(teamA, teamZ) {
  var col, row;
  
  col = $('#table_id td').filter(function() { //return column of teamA
    return $(this).html() === teamA.replace(' - ', '<br>');
  }).index(); 

  row = $('#table_id tr').filter(function() { ////return row of teamZ
    return $(this).html().indexOf(teamZ.replace(' - ', '<br>')) > -1;
  }).index();

  $('tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col).css('background-color', '#f00');
}

highlight('TeamA - 2', 'TeamZ - 9');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <td>Squares</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>1</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>2</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>3</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>4</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>5</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>6</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>7</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>8</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>9</td>
    <td>TeamA<br>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>3</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Mark</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">John</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>5</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Mike</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Earl</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>8</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Morris</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Brice</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>7</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Taylor</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Evan</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>9</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Mandy</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Mitch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>2</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Tony</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Jennifer</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>1</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Kristen</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Hector</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>4</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Gabby</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">David</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>6</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">George</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Steffanie</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TeamZ<br>0</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Breck</td>
    <td bgcolor="#89ff89">Terry</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: One question, when I put this in the entire (real) table, it always selects 1 cell up on the TeamZ side. Seems to be in this portion of the code : ` return $(this).html().indexOf(teamz.replace(' - ', '<br>')) > -1; `. Any Idea why?

Comment: Is your first row in a thead element in your real table?  Not sure what else would cause that.

Comment: Not that I see. Any way to force it to go 1 down?

Comment: I owe you a beer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all the table elements to find the matching values, then use CSS selectors to highlight the matched field.  Something like this will work:

```
winningAScore = 2;
winningZScore = 9;

//get top row
counter = 0;
$('#table_id tr:first-child td').each(function() {
    var strOut = $(this).html().replace(/Team[A-z]<br>/g,'');
  if(!isNaN(strOut) && strOut == winningAScore) {
        posnX = counter;
  }
  counter++;
})


//get first column row
counter = 0;
$('#table_id tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    var strOut = $(this).html().replace(/Team[A-z]<br>/g,'');
  if(!isNaN(strOut) && strOut == winningZScore) {
        posnY = counter;
  }
  counter++;
})

$('tr:eq('+posnY+') td:eq('+posnX+')').css('background-color', 'red');
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/8ybtntqg/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can do index based detect and selection in jQuery like so: `$('tr:eq(2) td:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'red');`

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPLNvB

Comment: That doesn't base the selection off of the TeamA or TeamZ score.

Comment: Your inquiry was "Let's say the winner would be whoever is in the cell that lines up with TeamA - 2 and TeamZ - 9. That would be Mitch. I want to highlight Mitch's cell ... based on the numbers of TeamA and TeamZ" so in that case, you replace the index value in my example with the TeamA/Z cell index.

Comment: I also said: but I want to automatically do it, based on the numbers of TeamA and TeamZ.